# Matt Kruse's JavaScript Calendar - today's date / other months dates

Tags: javascript, calendar

I have a question regarding the very nice (but non updated Calendar) from Matt Kruse on this Page: http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/calendarpopup/

(many samples and the codes are all there - here you find a simple example: http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/calendarpopup/simple.html)

The Calender works very well (iam using the "Lightbox / DIV-style display"), but it is not possible to deactivate or hide the highlighted "todays-Date" on the other month dates. 
(the calender looks and works like the standard Windows/Office- Calender - 
the "OtherMonthDates" are Shown in the color:grey)

**For example:** 
If you pick a date on todays-month - thats fine:
Today is May the 6th and this day is highlighted, when I view May.
But If I go back to April, May the 6th is still highlighted and I don't want this.

I have tried all, but I had only success to disable/"not display" the A-Tag from the "OtherMonthDates", but the current-date from the actual month, will still be shown on the other months.
 I have edited the css and - with this simple CSS workaround: to hide (only) the otherMonthDates of the current month:

```css
.TESTcpOtherMonthDate a {
     display: none;
}
```

Sorry for my bad english & thanks you for your help.

Comment: What is your question now, exactly? If you had success with your solution already, how do you want us to improve it?

Comment: Ahh Sorry, i see :), my question is: is there a solution to "hide" the "Current Selected Day" on the OtherMonths. My solution to hide the "OtherMonthDates" with the css code works for the very well, but not for the "selected/current Day".

Comment: I have updated my question and hope this is understandable now.

Comment: Today is May the 6th and this day is highlighted, when I view May. If I go back to April, May the 6th is still highlighted and you don't want this. Did I get you right?

Comment: I had a look at the site's code and from what I can tell, you will not be able to solve this with pure CSS. The current day's CSS class is always ``cpCurrentDate``, no matter whether you view the current or the last month. You will have to dig into the calendar's application logic to achieve what you want.

Comment: Yes you are right, there is a JS File "CalendarPopup.js" (I use the Combined version) with all the logic behind that, but I didn't found a solution there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go open the `CalendarPopup.js` script file.
2. Search for function `CP_getCalendar()` at the very end of the file.
3. Go find this piece of code:

```
if((display_month == this.currentDate.getMonth()+1) &&(display_date==this.currentDate.getDate()) &&(display_year==this.currentDate.getFullYear())){dateClass = "cpCurrentDate";}else if(display_month == month){dateClass = "cpCurrentMonthDate";}else{dateClass = "cpOtherMonthDate";}
```

and replace it with this piece of code:

```
if((display_month == this.currentDate.getMonth()+1) &&(display_date==this.currentDate.getDate()) &&(display_year==this.currentDate.getFullYear()) && (last_month == this.currentDate.getMonth())){dateClass = "cpCurrentDate";}else if(display_month == month){dateClass = "cpCurrentMonthDate";}else{dateClass = "cpOtherMonthDate";}
```

4. Now your calendar will look like expected. Current day will be highlighted, if you view the current month (left image) and the highlight will not be applied, if you view the last month (right image):

[image]

Comment: WOW, what a nice solution!!! Thank you very much for this! This is exactly what i wanted! Thx again.

Comment: This is what I've done minutes ago :D! But: "Vote Up requires 15 reputation" :/

Comment: Okay, now I've discovered the arrow :)!